# Blender magnification calculation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

I have a very simple scene:

- A 100 x 100 mm (h) rectangular plate at the origin
- A spotlight on the target
- A camera looking directly at the target. The camera is placed 1000 mm away from the target (d), uses f = 50 mm lenses and the sensor size is (2452, 2056) pixels, or (8.4594, 7.0932) mm, with the physical size of individual pixels of 3.45 x 3.45 µm^2 (pix).

I calculated the expected size of the object in the rendered image as:

- Magnification: M = f / (d - f) = 0.053
- Size of the object: o = h * M / h = 1525 pixels

When I rendered the image and measured the size of the object using ImageJ it turns out it is around 1450 pixels wide - so about 5% off from what I expected.

Could you help me find the error? Is my calculation off? Or is the rendering engine not following this simple pinhole model? I'm using cycles without any distortions.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems that the pinhole formulas work if you assume that the distance to the object (d) is in fact augmented by the focal length:
`d := d + f` (as if the pinhole was pushed back from the camera physical position by distance of f)

In my case then the equations read:

`M = f / (d + f - f) = 50 / 1000 = 0.05`

`o = h * M / pix_size = 100 * 0.05 / 0.00345 = 1450`

Which is what I measured empirically